# Python - "cannot unpack non-iterable int object" when importing json data into database

Tags: python, django

I'm working on an importer to import a list of facilities from a json file into my database. The importing works. But when i added some extra conditions to update existing facilities (whenever i run the script again and there is updated data inside the json) it stopped working the way it originally did. The updating works if i only have 1 facility inside the json file but if i add more than one i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\json\jsontest\data_import\management\commands\import_from_url.py", line 53, in import_facility_from_file
    facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.update(
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Also: Instead of updating it will just create two additional copies of one of the facilities.
Been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now but so far no luck.

## UPDATE:

I changed it to what was suggested in the comments, (to use update_or_create instead of update) but it still does not work. It seems like now instead of producing an error or updating the facility it creates a copy of the facility.

import_facility_from_file.py

```
import os
import json
import traceback
from data_import.models import Facility, FacilityAddress, FacilityInspectionInfo, FacilityComplaints
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from datetime import datetime
from jsontest.settings import BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def import_facility_from_file(self):
        print(BASE_DIR)
        data_folder = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'import_data', 'resources')

        for data_file in os.listdir(data_folder):
            with open(os.path.join(data_folder, data_file), encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
                data = json.loads(data_file.read())

                for key, data_object in data.items():
                    UUID = key
                    Name = data_object.get('Name', None)
                    IssuedNumber = data_object.get('IssuedNumber', None)
                    Capacity = data_object.get('Capacity', None)
                    Licensee = data_object.get('Licensee', None)
                    Email = data_object.get('Email', None)
                    AdministratorName = data_object.get('AdministratorName', None)
                    TelephoneNumber = data_object.get('TelephoneNumber', None)
                    ClosedTimestamp = data_object.get('ClosedTimestamp', None)
                    MostRecentLicenseTimestamp = data_object.get('MostRecentLicenseTimestamp', None)
                    PrimaryAddress = data_object["AddressInfo"]["PrimaryAddress"]
                    SecondaryAddress = data_object["AddressInfo"]["SecondaryAddress"]
                    City = data_object["AddressInfo"]["City"]
                    RegionOrState = data_object["AddressInfo"]["RegionOrState"]
                    PostalCode = data_object["AddressInfo"]["PostalCode"]
                    Geolocation = data_object["AddressInfo"]["Geolocation"]
                    ComplaintRelatedVisits = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["ComplaintRelatedVisits"]
                    InspectionRelatedVisits = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["InspectionRelatedVisits"]
                    NumberOfVisits = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["NumberOfVisits"]
                    LastVisitTimestamp = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["LastVisitTimestamp"]
                    ComplaintsTypeA = data_object["Complaints"]["ComplaintsTypeA"]
                    ComplaintsTypeB = data_object["Complaints"]["ComplaintsTypeB"]
                    SubstantiatedAllegations = data_object["Complaints"]["SubstantiatedAllegations"]
                    TotalAllegations = data_object["Complaints"]["TotalAllegations"]
                    LatestUpdateTimestamp = data_object.get('LatestUpdateTimestamp', None)

                    try:
                        if Facility.objects.filter(UUID=UUID, LatestUpdateTimestamp=LatestUpdateTimestamp):
                            full_traceback = 'No update required: Facility exists and is up to date'
                            print(full_traceback)

                        else:
                            facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.update_or_create(UUID=UUID,
                                defaults={
                                'Name': Name,
                                'IssuedNumber': IssuedNumber,
                                'Capacity': Capacity,
                                'Licensee': Licensee,
                                'Email': Email,
                                'AdministratorName': AdministratorName,
                                'TelephoneNumber': TelephoneNumber,
                                'ClosedTimestamp': ClosedTimestamp,                                                                  
                                'MostRecentLicenseTimestamp': MostRecentLicenseTimestamp,
                                'LatestUpdateTimestamp': LatestUpdateTimestamp
                                }                            
                            ),
                            facility_address, address_created = FacilityAddress.objects.update_or_create(
                                defaults={
                                'PrimaryAddress': PrimaryAddress,
                                'SecondaryAddress': SecondaryAddress,
                                'City': City,
                                'RegionOrState': RegionOrState,
                                'PostalCode': PostalCode,
                                'Geolocation': Geolocation,
                                'AddressInfo': facility
                                }                            
                            )
                            if address_created:
                                    facility_address.save()
                          
                    except Exception:
                        full_traceback = traceback.format_exc()

                        print(full_traceback)


    
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Call the function to import data
        """
        self.import_facility_from_file()
```

models.py

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    UUID = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    admin_uid = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    IssuedNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    mainimage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    Capacity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Licensee = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=True, blank=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    AdministratorName = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    TelephoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    ClosedTimestamp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MostRecentLicenseTimestamp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    LatestUpdateTimestamp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "facilities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name


class FacilityAddress(models.Model):
    PrimaryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    SecondaryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    RegionOrState = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    PostalCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Geolocation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    AddressInfo = models.ForeignKey(Facility, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "facility addresses"

    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.PrimaryAddress} {self.City}"


class FacilityInspectionInfo(models.Model):
    ComplaintRelatedVisits = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    InspectionRelatedVisits = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    NumberOfVisits = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    LastVisitTimestamp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    InspectionInfo = models.ForeignKey(Facility, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "facility inspection infos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.InspectionInfo.Name


class FacilityComplaints(models.Model):
    ComplaintsTypeA = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ComplaintsTypeB = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    SubstantiatedAllegations = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    TotalAllegations = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Complaints = models.ForeignKey(Facility, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "facility complaints"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Complaints.Name
```

json file

```
{"00016ed7be4872a19d6e16afc98a7389b2bb324a2":
{"UUID":"00016ed7be4872a19d6e1ed6f36b647f3eb41cadedd2130b103a5851caebc26fbbbf24c2f1a64d2cf34ac4e03aaa30309816f58c397e6afc98a7389b2bb324a2","Name":"Test Facility","IssuedNumber":"123456","Licensee":"Test Licensee","Email":"test@example.com","AdministratorName":"Test Name","TelephoneNumber":"(123) 456-7890324879","LatestUpdateTimestamp":"1362985200",
    "AddressInfo":{"PrimaryAddress":"123 Fake Road","SecondaryAddress":"","City":"Testcity","RegionOrState":"TX","PostalCode":"12345","Geolocation":"00.0000,-00.0000"},"Capacity":100,"MostRecentLicenseTimestamp":1575180000,"ClosedTimestamp":0,
    "InspectionInfo":{"ComplaintRelatedVisits":0,"InspectionRelatedVisits":0,"NumberOfVisits":0,"LastVisitTimestamp":0},
    "Complaints":{"ComplaintsTypeA":0,"ComplaintsTypeB":0,"SubstantiatedAllegations":0,"TotalAllegations":0}},
    
"00016ed7be4872a15435435435b2bb324a2":
{"UUID":"000c93dcb7a0b3d5783bb330892aff6abdb9fb57a7d3701c2d903f3640877579f3173ecd8a80532f6c3d53dbacde78a6a54ae42fef321a5793f5a01934f8de7a","Name":"Test Facility 2","IssuedNumber":"123456","Licensee":"Test Licensee","Email":"test@example.com","AdministratorName":"Test Name","TelephoneNumber":"(123) 456-7890324879","LatestUpdateTimestamp":"1362985200",
    "AddressInfo":{"PrimaryAddress":"123 Fake Road","SecondaryAddress":"","City":"Testcity","RegionOrState":"TX","PostalCode":"12345","Geolocation":"00.0000,-00.0000"},"Capacity":100,"MostRecentLicenseTimestamp":1575180000,"ClosedTimestamp":0,
    "InspectionInfo":{"ComplaintRelatedVisits":0,"InspectionRelatedVisits":0,"NumberOfVisits":0,"LastVisitTimestamp":0},
    "Complaints":{"ComplaintsTypeA":0,"ComplaintsTypeB":0,"SubstantiatedAllegations":0,"TotalAllegations":0}},

"00234324324343243afc98a7389b2bb324a2":
{"UUID":"fffd4dec10054e6e1deb2a2266a7c6bb0136ba46222e734ceed5855651f735cfbe0bb66cfaf27c3d175ae261a8f6df0c36b5390d15c70b07d67e35e1081aaf6d","Name":"Test Facility 3","IssuedNumber":"123456","Licensee":"Test Licensee","Email":"test@example.com","AdministratorName":"Test Name","TelephoneNumber":"(123) 456-7890324879","LatestUpdateTimestamp":"1362985200",
    "AddressInfo":{"PrimaryAddress":"123 Fake Road","SecondaryAddress":"","City":"Testcity","RegionOrState":"TX","PostalCode":"12345","Geolocation":"00.0000,-00.0000"},"Capacity":100,"MostRecentLicenseTimestamp":1575180000,"ClosedTimestamp":0,
    "InspectionInfo":{"ComplaintRelatedVisits":0,"InspectionRelatedVisits":0,"NumberOfVisits":0,"LastVisitTimestamp":0},
    "Complaints":{"ComplaintsTypeA":0,"ComplaintsTypeB":0,"SubstantiatedAllegations":0,"TotalAllegations":0}}}
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of your error. It's quite inconvenient to check the whole code you have given to find the exact line with the error.

Comment: It is line 52 in the "import_facility_from_file.py" file. It did not give me a full traceback

Comment: I couldn't look inside your computer to see what `import_facility_from_file` contains. And you need to know how to see the full traceback; the ability to read the traceback solves lots of issues. Maybe someone would like to waste their time without it, but I wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added a full traceback and this is what i got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dtg\OneDrive\Desktop\Sync\json\jsontest\data_import\management\commands\import_from_url.py", line 53, in import_facility_from_file
    facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.update(
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: It's not a full traceback, but in this particular situation it's enough to understand the issue. I'll add the answer.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but shouldn't `facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.update(` be `facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.update_or_create(`?

Comment: You are correct. I tried that first, but it will create new entries instead of updating them. I tried it like this: facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.filter(UUID=UUID).update_or_create( UUID=UUID,

Comment: Not sure I get it yet, but I thought the idea was to create a new Facility object if the query was not found, or just update it if it is found.  If you just want to update then perhaps `Facility.objects.filter(UUID=UUID).update(` would be enough.  But if you stick with update_or_create, I don't think you need the filter(UUID=UUID) part.

Comment: You are correct. I used update but when i use that without the filter method i get: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following if you want to create a new object if one is not found to be updated, or update it if it is.  UUID=UUID would be the **kwargs used to find the object to be updated, otherwise one would be created.  The defaults would be what you want to update the fields with. This is documented in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create.

I tried the code below, and it seems to work, although I'm not sure if this is what you want.  I only did the Facility objects, not the others to see if it works.  I removed the try/except and the exists() since I don't think you need them with the update_or_create() method.  I also removed the get_or_create() since again, I think that is not needed since update_or_create() should take care of that as well.

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def import_facility_from_file(self):
        print("BASE", BASE_DIR)
        data_folder = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'import_data', 'resources')

        for data_file in os.listdir(data_folder):
            with open(os.path.join(data_folder, data_file), encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
                data = json.loads(data_file.read())

                for key, data_object in data.items():
                    UUID = data_object.get('UUID', None)
                    Name = data_object.get('Name', None)
                    IssuedNumber = data_object.get('IssuedNumber', None)
                    Capacity = data_object.get('Capacity', None)
                    Licensee = data_object.get('Licensee', None)
                    Email = data_object.get('Email', None)
                    AdministratorName = data_object.get('AdministratorName', None)
                    TelephoneNumber = data_object.get('TelephoneNumber', None)
                    ClosedTimestamp = data_object.get('ClosedTimestamp', None)
                    MostRecentLicenseTimestamp = data_object.get('MostRecentLicenseTimestamp', None)
                    PrimaryAddress = data_object["AddressInfo"]["PrimaryAddress"]
                    SecondaryAddress = data_object["AddressInfo"]["SecondaryAddress"]
                    City = data_object["AddressInfo"]["City"]
                    RegionOrState = data_object["AddressInfo"]["RegionOrState"]
                    PostalCode = data_object["AddressInfo"]["PostalCode"]
                    Geolocation = data_object["AddressInfo"]["Geolocation"]
                    ComplaintRelatedVisits = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["ComplaintRelatedVisits"]
                    InspectionRelatedVisits = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["InspectionRelatedVisits"]
                    NumberOfVisits = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["NumberOfVisits"]
                    LastVisitTimestamp = data_object["InspectionInfo"]["LastVisitTimestamp"]
                    ComplaintsTypeA = data_object["Complaints"]["ComplaintsTypeA"]
                    ComplaintsTypeB = data_object["Complaints"]["ComplaintsTypeB"]
                    SubstantiatedAllegations = data_object["Complaints"]["SubstantiatedAllegations"]
                    TotalAllegations = data_object["Complaints"]["TotalAllegations"]
                    LatestUpdateTimestamp = data_object.get('LatestUpdateTimestamp', None)

                    print(Facility.objects.filter(UUID=UUID, LatestUpdateTimestamp=LatestUpdateTimestamp))    #what does this show?
                    if Facility.objects.filter(UUID=UUID, LatestUpdateTimestamp=LatestUpdateTimestamp):
                        print(Facility, UUID) #what does this show?
                        msg = "\n\nfacility exists and is up to date: {}\n{}".format(Name, str())
                        print(msg)

                    else:
                        print("UPDATE")
                        facility, facility_created = Facility.objects.update_or_create(UUID=UUID,
                            defaults={
                            'Name': Name,
                            'IssuedNumber': IssuedNumber,
                            'Capacity': Capacity,
                            'Licensee': Licensee,
                            'Email': Email,
                            'AdministratorName': AdministratorName,
                            'TelephoneNumber': TelephoneNumber,
                            'ClosedTimestamp': ClosedTimestamp,
                            'MostRecentLicenseTimestamp': MostRecentLicenseTimestamp,
                            'LatestUpdateTimestamp': LatestUpdateTimestamp
                            }
                        )


    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        """
        Call the function to import data
        """
        self.import_facility_from_file()
```

Comment: This works a bit better but it will only work on the first object which has the id 1. And it will only update object 1 if i change all 3 facilities. The other two will stay the same.

Comment: Not sure why this happens.  I'll keep trying.  But `UUID = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)` I beleive should be `UUID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)` and make sure to `import uuid`

Comment: Question.  What will `print(key)` print if added after `for key, data_object in data.items():`

Comment: i get this when i change the UUID field as suggested:     raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“fffd4dec10054e6e1deb2a2266a7c6bb0136ba46222e734ceed5855651f735cfbe0bb66cfaf27c3d175ae261a8f6df0c36b5390d15c70b07d67e35e1081aaf6d” is not a valid UUID.'] The code in your question returns the three UUID's as a list

Comment: Try `UUID = key` instead of `UUID = data_object.get('UUID', None)`, but otherwise, sorry, I'm out of ideas.  I'll keep trying though.

Comment: Now if i delete all facilities, reimport them and then try to re import them it will import only the first one but tell me all 3 are imported. Edit: I just tried again. Now it's importing them again but now the updating doesn't work anymore

Comment: basically i think both "key" and UUID bring me the same results so the issue seems somewhere else, idk. I appreciate your help a lot though.

Comment: I updated the answer.  It seems to do work, but I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: That was a great idea! Thank you so much for your efforts. I really appreciate it. I think i over complicated it. The only thing that doesn't work is the foreign key values like FacilityAddress, FacilityInspectionInfo, FacilityComplaints. The strange thing is that it works with get_or_create though

Comment: Got address to work. Mistake on my end. Forgot to change the changed date in the backend :D

Comment: Hey @Matthias, I checked the link you sent before, and I do think the answer about filtering is useful, you should filter by UUID as well, otherwise two different Facility objects that happen to have the same timestamp, would trigger the if statement.  I've updated my answer to show you how to filter for this, but like this filter(A, B), and not filter(A).filter(B), though I don't really know if that would make a difference.  I also think you might want a print statement after the if, as I did above, or try print(Facility.objects.filter(UUID=UUID, LatestUpdateTimestamp=LatestUpdateTimestamp))